# Unable to locate package gcc-4.6-base:i386

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, gcc4.6

I'm having trouble with running a script to install prerequisite packages, which  requires gcc-4.6-base:i386, and don't know how to install it with aptitude or something similar. For reference, I'm currently running Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2. The error messages I'm getting are:

```
E:  Unable to locate package gcc-4.6-base:i386
E:  Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-4.6-base'
E:  Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-4.6-base'
```

It looks like the binary package can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/i386/gcc-4.6-base). Furthermore, I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736010/how-do-i-install-gcc-4-6-on-ubuntu-15-10-32bit-edition) out but to no avail. I've also done multiple rounds of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install`. For reference, this is an Ardupilot project and I'm following along [here](http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/building-px4-for-linux-with-make.html), getting stuck on running the script `Tools/scripts/install-prereqs-ubuntu.sh -y`.

Any and all help appreciated, and I'd be happy to provide more info if need be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all those incompatibilities stemmed from the fact that I needed the 32-bit (i386) version of Ubuntu 14.04, not the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 16.04.